# Influye la fuente en el ancho del border?

Tags: css

Estoy desarrollando una web en la que hay diferentes botones que debo darles un `border`. La cuestión es que con `border: 1px solid #831452` el borde es muy fino y con `border: 2px solid #831452` el borde me parece demasiado grueso.

Aquí viene mi duda, es posible que la fuente que esté utilizando (en mi caso [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?preview.text_type=custom)) influya en el ancho del border?

Mis razones para pensarlo son que, tanto para `1.1px` como para `1.9px`, el ancho del botón es exactamente el mismo:

[image: Muestra de border con 1.1px][image: Muestra de border con 1.9px]

La cuestión es que me suena haber tocado webs (no mías) en las que se le podía poner decimal al border, por eso mi pregunta es si el border depende de la fuente o de que puede depender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La fuente no está influyendo en tu resultado, porque además de que la fuente solamente afecta al texto, un pixel es un pixel tanto en *Roboto* como en *Comic Sans*.

La propiedad `border` no contempla los píxeles decimales, pero podrías usar una propiedad que si los contempla, `box-shadow`.

```css
.cajas {
  display: flex;
}

.caja {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.uno {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dos {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1.5px black;
}

.tres {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cajas">
  <div class="caja uno"><strong>1px</strong></div>
  <div class="caja dos"><strong>1.5px<strong></div>
  <div class="caja tres"><strong>2px</strong></div>
</div>
```

Esto es en fondo un "truquillo" para conseguir lo que quieres, yo obtaría por elegir un grosor de **1px** o **2px**.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por la explicación! A parte del hecho de que el border "ocupa espacio" en el layout y el box-shadow no, hay alguna otra diferencia?

Comment: Son dos propiedades que se usan para distintas cosas. Con `border` puedes definir distintos estilos de borde (dotted, dashed...) y con `box-shadow` defines la colocación de la sombra, su difuminado... Se usan realmente para cosas distintas aunque en tu caso se puedan usar para lo mismo. De hecho no son excluyentes y puedes usar ambos a la vez.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por tu tiempo y por la explicación! :)